# dropdown list items repeat on surface pro when touch scrolling

Tags: html, scroll, surface

windows surface pro 1, IE 11.0.9600

Open a web page that has dropdown list, touching and scrolling items inside the dropdown list, the items will be displayed repeatedly.

Is this designed for specific purpose or it's a bug in windows pro?

Comment: did you ever find a solution for this? We are experiencing this on our web app on a surface pro 4 IE 11

Comment: I actually forgot, highly possibility didn't fix it.